# Checking injectivity of a map out of a tensor product: suffice to check the decomposable tensors?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

In showing that the map $$\Phi: \hom(V,V')\otimes \hom(W,W') \to \hom(V\otimes W, V'\otimes W')\\ [ \Phi(\sigma \otimes \tau)](v\otimes w)=\sigma v \otimes \tau w$$

is injective, the proof in Roman's linear algebra book only checks that a nonzero decomposable tensor $\sigma \otimes \tau$ cannot be mapped to zero. Why does it suffice to check only the decomposable tensors?

**Edit:** I now see that this has been fixed in the next edition of the text.

Comment: 1. Throw the book away. 2. Look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72013/

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg In the link provided, why does $\Phi \left( \sum_i \sigma_i \otimes \tau_i \right) = 0 \implies \sum_i \lambda(\sigma_i(v))\tau_i = 0 \in \hom (W, W')$ for all $\lambda \in (V')^*$?

Comment: Oh, I see, $(v, w) \mapsto \lambda(v)w$ is bilinear.